# New menu in Unity panel

Tags: unity, 11.04, nautilus-elementary

I just rebooted my computer, and now I have this menu on my Unity panel when no windows have focus. I have nautilus-elementary  installed, and when I go to "About" in this menu it brings up a splash-info-thing for nautilus-elementary , leading me to believe that nautilus-elementary  put it there. Here is a quick video: http://vid.ly/0t1s3j

Am I insane and this has been around the entire time? Is there a way to remove this? I haven't decided if I like it yet, but right now it seems redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. The desktop on Ubuntu is provided by Nautilus. When are are using items on your desktop, you are actually using nautilus.

I think it is fine to have a menu for the desktop. If you think the desktop should not have a menu or nautilus menu should be superseded with a custom one for the desktop, you should consider filing a bug in Unity. http://bugs.launchpad.net/unity